# Ext.Button into Ext.List Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am new in Sencha Touch
Can I add Ext.Button into a Ext.List
if yes then how

Thanks
Amit Battan

Answer (score 1):

It's been discussed on the Sencha Forum...

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?118790-Buttons-%28and-other-widgets%29-in-Ext.List-or-Ext.DataView

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Maybe it's possible but I'm sure very complicated. Do you need to add the button per list item or per list? If per list item, do you need to add more the one button?

Answer (score 0):

From the question, as simple as it is, the only way that I have been able to get a button into a list is by creating a titlebar and docked to the top and in that titlebar having a button in it.  This can be achieved in a view file.

```
   this.add({
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Courses',
                items:[{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    align: 'left',
                    iconCls: 'add',
                    iconMask: true,
                    handler: function(){
                        var panel = Ext.create('UniversityData.view.EntryForm');
                        panel.showBy(this);
                    }
                    }]
            });
```

This would go in your view's config section